# Efecto curioso de limpieza/filtrado al transcribir preguntas de SOen

Tags: discusión, traducciones-de-contenido

No sé si alguno se había fijado ya, pero me he dado cuenta de que al transcribir preguntas y respuestas del sitio en inglés, ocurre el fenónemo de que no se transcriben todas las respuestas, como es lógico, y de alguna forma queda una relación *pregunta* <-> *respuesta* más directa. Al omitir otras respuestas, en parte se pierde información (es lógico que las segundas y terceras respuestas tengan información interesante), pero por otro lado también se eliminan las respuestas similares, que no aportan mucho más y, lógico, también las respuestas no tan correctas o completas...

¿Qué opináis?

---

De hecho, lanzo un órdago a los ávidos traductores, jeje, de, al traducir una respuesta del inglés, intentar mejorarla añadiendo información de 2ª o 3ª respuestas para obtener una respuesta más completa y condensada que en el sitio inglés...